# What do Active Directory LDAP users enter as a username to login to OBIEE analytics?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, obiee

WebLogic and LDAP are integrated, I can see users and groups in the Console security realm. Setup was minimal - simply added and set specs for an AD provider, nothing else.

However, all username combinations I've tried end up in wrong user/password in the analytics login screen, and "access denied" in the BI cluster log.

So what should be the username syntax that AD accounts are to enter? I am trying to allow any AD account to be able to login at this point.

**UPDATED** per @Chris request:

WL version 12.2.1

Documentation: very vague help screens from the WL console, missing the part I'm trying to figure out specifically

Error from the managed server log/obis1: BI security access is denied - web service credentials are invalid

The account works, however, in Windows Network, AD Server, and is visible inside WL with its specific AD group.

Comment: a) What EXACT version are you using? Exact...not "12c"...

b) Which documentation did you follow?

c) What do the log files say

With such an unprecise problem description it's impossible to say what you did wrong

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer to this: you can use the same exact credentials you would while logging to the AD server directly. Getting "invalid user/password" error can be indicative of a lot of other problems stemming from the LDAP Authenticator configuration.